# JFrog Artifactory - 404 Resource has expired

Tags: artifactory

**Scenario:**

- Code is in Nuget packages, which get pushed to a local Artifactory
  respository in Location 1 (DEV/QA). Each code change results in a new version number (i.e. different package, not overwriting existing package).
- Artifactory in location 2 (Main colo) has a remote repository that replicates these packages from Location 1.
- Artifactories in Locations 3, 4 and 5 (Production colos around the
  world) have remote repositories that replicate these packages from
  Location 2.
- When code is deployed to production SaaS servers, the packages are pulled down from Artifactories in locations 3, 4 and 5.

**Problem:**
Intermittent problem where packages in remote repositories become `expired` and give a `404 error` when you attempt to download them.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Resource has expired"
  } ]
}
```

**Request:**
Is there some setting I can set somewhere that will cause resources to NEVER expire? (We have a cap of 100 versions in the original location, to control growth and the downstream remote repositories are set to delete packages when the origin deletes them)

I am unable to find anything in the documentation that even hints this is possible.

Comment: are those pre-relese versions? can you provide an example of the version numbering?

Comment: We use Semantic Versioning.
Major.Minor.Patch

Not sure what you mean by "pre-release versions". We don't have any distinction between versions other than the version numbering and the code inside the package(s).

Comment: [NuGer pre-relese versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages)

Comment: Dev team says no, we don't use pre-release versions.

Comment: If you can provide a few examples of the version names, this might help with better understanding the cause of this issue

Comment: @PeterBollwerk did you found a solution for this problem?